# How do I change bootstrap 3 version column order in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried to change the column order in desktop view and mobile view. In mobile view, `Last Name` should be in 2nd place where in desktop, it should be in last.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="container active col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container active col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-push-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container active col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-pull-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Address</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container active col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-pull-3 ">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Company</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I guess that's what it is.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh, I want Last Name in another row and rest should be in one row. Please help me.

Comment: It is working as you are expecting. `Last Name` is in last in desktop and it is in second in mobile. I have checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using **Flex** and adding **Media-Query** will solve your problem very easily.

There will be a way to get it done using Bootstrap Grid, i.e using `col-md-push-4` and etc.

But it's very much convenient using flex and adding `order` to inner elements.

Very useful **[Flexbox documentation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

```css
.outer {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/*For Mobile*/

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .inner {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }
  .fn {
    order: 1;
  }
  .ln {
    order: 2;
  }
  .add {
    order: 3;
  }
  .co {
    order: 4;
  }
}


/*For Desktop which we are working for*/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .inner {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }
  .fn {
    order: 1;
  }
  .ln {
    order: 3;
  }
  .add {
    order: 2;
  }
  .co {
    order: 4;
  }
}


/*For Large Screen*/

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .inner {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }
  .fn {
    order: 1;
  }
  .ln {
    order: 4;
  }
  .add {
    order: 2;
  }
  .co {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner fn">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background:red; color:white;">First Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="inner ln">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background:green; color:white;">Last Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner add">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background:blue; color:white;">Address</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner co">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="background:orange; color:white;">Company</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, `Last Name` should be in next row which is not happening at this moment. I want `First Name` `Address` and `Company` in the same row and `Last Name` should be in another row in desktop view. For mobile, it is working perfectly fine. Can you please help me to do this. Thank you.

Comment: If you are flexible in using a different approach, try using flex.
Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using push & pull which will only work for the desktop/tablet viewports.

Best is to develop for the mobile as per your need and then use push & pull for the desktop/tablet to make the re-arrangement.

I have achieved similar ordering using the same approach. It works very well.

**Update:**

Adding the plunker for the same : http://plnkr.co/edit/b2PNXyyXOsXUx51LweJI?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-3 cell cell-1">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-3 cell cell-2">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 cell cell-3">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 cell cell-4">
            4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.cell {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me a sample solution for this? Thank you

Comment: @Raj, added the plunker for you to refer. As you are using bootstrap, you should be leveraging the features and not add additional CSS to achieve what is possible using the existing. The accepted answer is perfectly correct but it forces you to add additional code.